# unable to set property 'innerHTML' of undefined or null reference. IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am trying to post a form and open in a new window.  Works fine on Chrome and Firefox getting the following error in IE.

I am getting the following error in IE only. Can somebody please help me out finding a solution or alternate.

[image]

code :

```
function SubmitForm(actionUrl, Nums ) {
 var sHTML = "<form id='form1' action='" + actionUrl + "' method='post' target='MLSmap'>";
    sHTML += "<input name= num type='hidden' value='" + Nums + "' />";   
    sHTML += "</form>";

    var frmTosubmt = window.open(actionUrl, "MLSmap","width:500px; height:700px");
    frmTosubmt.document.body.innerHTML = sHTML ;
    frmTosubmt.form1.submit();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

When you open a window from a URL, you probably have to provide a little bit of time for the browser to process that URL and actually get the document open before you can reference its contents.  Different browsers will handle that timing differently and it may also depend upon whether the contents is cached or not (you should test with both cached and non-cached URLs).

You could, for example do this:

```
var frmTosubmt = window.open(actionUrl, "NewWindow","width:500px; height:700px");
frmTosubmt.onload = function() {
    frmTosubmt.document.body.innerHTML = sHTML;
    fmrTosubmt.frmMap.submit();
}
```

But, if you're replacing the entire body contents, I wonder why you're bothering to open a URL at all.  Why not just open a blank window and then fill in the contents?  Or, if all you're trying to do is submit a form, why not just use an Ajax post from your current window?  Why bother opening a new window.

Also, your screenshot shows `frmTosubmt.form1.submit()`, but that isn't what's in the HTML.  Your code shows something different.  Not sure why those are different?

Comment: Thank you. sorry I corrected. The requirement is to post to a new window.

Comment: tried ur suggestion. now I don't see the error but I don't see the desired results.  In this function I am trying to post to bingmaps. Now the window with bingmaps opens the values are not getting posted hence I don't see the result.

Comment: What do you mean "the window with bingmaps"?  You're trying to replace the entire contents of the body in that window so there would be no other contents.  What is bingmaps and why would it be in the window at all if you're trying to replace the entire contents of the window?  Something just doesn't make sense here?  Also, you may have cross-domain access security issues if `actionUrl` isn't the same domain as your parent page.

Comment: I am trying to show  a location in map in a new window. Cross-domain is not a issue because the domain is a registered domain.

Comment: @BumbleBee - Two questions then.  1) How you can show a location in map in a new window when you are replacing the entire contents of the window with a simple form with nothing visible in it?  That will replace everything in the window.  2) Registered domain has NOTHING to do with cross-domain.  If the domain is different than the domain of the parent page, some operations may be blocked for security reasons.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried "open a blank window and then fill in the contents" and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Tried the suggestion by `jfriend00` "open a blank window and then fill in the contents" and that worked.

```
function (url, params, target) {
     var form = ['<form method="POST" id= "frmpopup" action="', url, '" target="', target, '">'];
        for (var key in params)
            form.push('<input type="hidden" name="', key, '" value="', params[key], '"/>');
        form.push('</form>');
        jQuery(form.join('')).appendTo('body')[0];

        window.open('', target, "width:500px; height:700px; resi");
        $("#frmpopup").submit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the Script Block that calls your JavaScript File to the botton of your HTML page beneath the closing body tag (.

We are getting the error `unable to set property 'innerHTML' of undefined or null reference` because, we are trying to execute our JavaScript file before our webpage is loaded. This means we are trying to write to a page that technically doesn't exist.